Can I stop macOS from hiding a hidden app's windows in the app's Dock menu?
In recent versions of macOS (14.x / Sonoma at least), when an app is hidden, all its currently open windows are also hidden in its Dock menu… except those that are currently minimized in the Dock.
What’s the logic behind this “feature”? Why would I want hidden windows to be hidden in the Dock menu as well? More precisely: why would I not want to be able to access a specific window directly through its parent app’s Dock menu when the app happens to be hidden? I don't hide apps because I don't want to be able to access their windows. I (temporarily) hide apps because their windows are sometimes hiding my view of other windows.
And most important: is there a way to turn this behaviour off?



Interesting, I can confirm this (surprising) behavior, I suspect it's a bug, because it doesn't make much sense. To your second question, I don't think you can turn it off (at least I haven't found any way to configure the Dock to behave differently). Let's see if macOS Sequoia fixes it...

If it's a "bug" as you say, the question is: why hasn't it been noticed and fixed? Surely it's a bug that is idiotic and egregious enough that it's senseless to force users to live with it for such a long time. (Sonoma came out a year ago.) I find it hard to believe that it's a bug. It's almost easier to believe that macOS engineers are so clueless about how macOS is used in the real world that they have implemented this deliberately. That would explain why it hasn't been fixed.

I understand your frustration. Things like this can be very annoying. Sequoia is around the corner, let's see if it's fixed, otherwise you may want to report it as a bug here: https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos/. I still suspect it's a bug and it's quite possible it has been noticed and reported, but has a low priority, that would explain why it's not fixed (yet). Of course, it could be a conscious design decision from macOS engineers. In that case, I'd love to know the rationale!
